# CSS Trick with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, blur

Today is April Fools Day, I want to trick my visitors with CSS3 Blur. The blur should last for 2 seconds and turn back to normal in 1 second.

But the problem is my code didn't executed as I expected.
The page now showing: Loaded > Blur > Normal > Blur
The page expected: Loaded > Blur > Normal <s>> Blur</s>

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".apffilter").addClass("animae");
    
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(".apffilter").removeClass("animae");
   }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.apffilter {
  filter:blur(1px);
  -webkit-filter:blur(1px);
  -moz-filter:blur(1px);
  -o-filter:blur(1px);
  -ms-filter:blur(1px);
    
  -webkit-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  -moz-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  -ms-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  -o-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
}

.apffilter.animae {
   filter:blur(0px);
  -webkit-filter:blur(0px);
  -moz-filter:blur(0px);
  -o-filter:blur(0px);
  -ms-filter:blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="apffilter">
    <img src="http://www.etnforum.com/templates/thewei-zz3/images/etnDiamond2015.png" /><br /><br />
    Happy April Fool's Day!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the `JS` which works fine. Just replace `addclass` event.

### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".apffilter").removeClass("animae");

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(".apffilter").addClass("animae");
        }, 3000);
    });
```

For OP request added Demo here as well!

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".apffilter").removeClass("animae");

            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $(".apffilter").addClass("animae");
            }, 3000);
        });
```

```css
.apffilter {
  filter:blur(0px);
  -webkit-filter:blur(1px);
  -moz-filter:blur(1px);
  -o-filter:blur(1px);
  -ms-filter:blur(1px);
    
  -webkit-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  -moz-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  -ms-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  -o-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
}

.apffilter.animae {
   filter:blur(1px);
  -webkit-filter:blur(0px);
  -moz-filter:blur(0px);
  -o-filter:blur(0px);
  -ms-filter:blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apffilter">
    <img src="http://www.etnforum.com/templates/thewei-zz3/images/etnDiamond2015.png" /><br /><br />
    Happy April Fool's Day!
</div>
```

[Here is the working model](https://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/9L6t751f/1/)

Comment: Not work at all, but how come I accepted your answer? Well ... April Fools Day ... (It worked)

Comment: Can you explain why only filter has to switch the pixels in CSS?

Comment: Hi @Doru, please mention the code you have trid . and wht means *doesn't work*?

Comment: The fiddle example of the accepted answer doesn't work like it should:  Loaded > Blur > Normal. Look yourself

Comment: dear it is as, LOAD --> BLUR *immediatly* --> *after **3** seconds* FORMAL. wait till effect completes

Comment: What I see is that the picture remains blurred forever

Comment: dear @doru, edited answer, now here you can see the effect? Don't say *NO*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74237/discussion-between-vikrant-and-doru).

Answer (score 2):

See below, you only add the blur to the `.animae` class, not the `.appfilter` class, I've left it there to show it should only be used to reset the blur

[Click here to see a fiddle of it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/9L6t751f/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".apffilter").addClass("animae");
    
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(".apffilter").removeClass("animae");
   }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.apffilter {
  filter:blur(0px);
  -webkit-filter:blur(0px);
  -moz-filter:blur(0px);
  -o-filter:blur(0px);
  -ms-filter:blur(0px);
    
  -webkit-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  -moz-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  -ms-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  -o-transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
  transition: all 2.0s linear 1.0s;
}

.apffilter.animae {
   filter:blur(1px);
  -webkit-filter:blur(1px);
  -moz-filter:blur(1px);
  -o-filter:blur(1px);
  -ms-filter:blur(1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="apffilter">
    <img src="http://www.etnforum.com/templates/thewei-zz3/images/etnDiamond2015.png" /><br /><br />
    Happy April Fool's Day!
</div>
```

Comment: Your code kept blur all the time. Didn't go back to normal.

Comment: Have a look again at the answer, I've added a fiddle

Comment: Arrgh - forgot all prefixes, answer updated, works now in all browsers - check here https://jsfiddle.net/9L6t751f/2/